# When I can find log file in the play?

Tags: playframework, frameworks, playframework-1.x

In which folder is a file with the log? Application mode is **DEV**.

> Play version is 1.3.1.

Comment: Take a look in your application/logs/ directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom file as **conf/log4j.properties** which includes:

```
log4j.rootLogger=Rolling

# Rolling files
log4j.appender.Rolling.File=/var/log/application.log //This is your log-file path
```

After that you have to refer this file from **conf/application.conf** as:

```
application.log.path=/log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, it is displayed only in the console.
If you want to output to a file, you must create a log4j configuration file.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/production#logging